# Gulp doesn't create a node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I think Gulp should create a node_modules folder in my project when I run `npm install --save-dev gulp`, but it doesn't. Why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Npm should create it. Can you provide a little more info what happens? :) Do you get any errors or other output?

Answer (score 1):

If your current working directory when you run npm install doesn't have a package.json file, it'll go up the tree until it finds one to put the entry for gulp into, then put the gulp folder in that folder's node_modules directory.  Try `npm init` before `npm install` and see what I mean.

Comment: Npm will create `node_modules` directory even if it doesn't find package.json.

Comment: If there is neither a package.JSON nor node_modules in the working directory, npm will not create them on npm install, it'll traverse up until it finds them or until it reaches the uaerbhome directory, @heikki

Comment: On my machine it does create it. Empty folder is enough. :)

Comment: npm install docs say otherwise.  Not sure what's in your environment, but the correct behavior is dependent on whether the cwd is considered a 'package' by npm or not.  https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Comment: Yes, before answering the question the first time. On my machine it works as I said, and as the docs describe. I'm on npm v1.4.9.

Comment: What part of the docs are you referring to? I can't find anything related to this. `npm -v -> 2.1.5`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html -> "If no package root is found, then the current folder is used."

Comment: That looks like the difference, then.  If it walks up my directory tree, it will find a node_modules folder in my home path, which it takes to be the package root.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so actually you need to help the system by creating a folder named `node_modules` and retype the command.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11256992)

Comment: This solution was already provided in an [earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26641814/1906307) that predates yours by more than a year.

Answer (score -2):

You must first create the folder `node_modules`, otherwise NPM install the module in the next-higher-level `node_modules` directory (eg your home directory).

Just type `mkdir node_modules` in the console to create the folder in the current directory. After that it should work as expected.

**Update**: If a `package.json` file in the directory exists, then NPM creates the folder `node_modules` automatically. With `npm init` you can generate a `package.json` file. This is the better way. Thanks to @Paul

Comment: This is incorrect.  If you have a package.json file in the current working directory, npm will create node_modules for you.